# how to set size for each fxml page in javafx

Tags: eclipse, javafx, fxml

I am creating a login  form and registration form in eclipse using javafx ... when application run it is showing default size for login and registration form..  both forms have different size.. how to update it ?

code is as follows

Samplecontroller.java

```
 public void signin() {
            AnchorPane pane2;

            try {
                pane2 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Login.fxml"))       
                root.getChildren().setAll(pane2);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

FXML

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="435.0" prefWidth="655.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8">
   <children>
      <ImageView fitHeight="435.0" fitWidth="655.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../image/reg1.jpeg" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <Label layoutX="278.0" layoutY="72.0" prefHeight="22.0" prefWidth="212.0" text="Login" textFill="#f8f7f7">
         <font>
            <Font name="Arial Bold Italic" size="39.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="38.0" layoutY="229.0" text="Email id" textFill="#19f236">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="28.0" />
         </font>
  </Label>
  <Label layoutX="38.0" layoutY="309.0" text="Login id" textFill="#19f236">
     <font>
        <Font name="System Bold" size="22.0" />
     </font>
  </Label>
  <TextField layoutX="204.0" layoutY="237.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="326.0" />
  <TextField layoutX="209.0" layoutY="313.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="326.0" />
  <Button layoutX="252.0" layoutY="374.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Login" />
  <Button layoutX="428.0" layoutY="374.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Cancel" />
  <Label layoutX="52.0" layoutY="357.0" textFill="#ee1111">
     <font>
        <Font size="28.0" />
     </font>
  </Label>
```

and in main class

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Sample.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,300,300);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is "default size"? What is "different size"? What is the shortest code you can show to recreate your issue? Do you use FXML? If so post it in your question. If there is not more information you will likely receive downvotes and no answer on top.

Comment: @geisterfurz007 default size is 300,300 and login page size is 435.0,635.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in the main class you are setting the scene width and height by 300 it will override the height and width set in the fxml file while launching. 
So i suggest you to set only the root to the scene

```
Scene scene = new Scene(root);
```

This will allow to take the height and width from the fxml file

Comment: 1st page is running but in second (loginpage) is not showing is size

Comment: when you are loading the login fxml, you set it on the root. So basically you are adding the login.fxml in the previous anchorpane. Try load into a new scene or set the height and width of anchorpane (first one) while loading login.fxml

Comment: actually there is 2 pages 1st reg(home page) and another is login page. as per your code it is fit for home page but not fit for login page .. so I want to fit the login page based  on  there own sizes..

Comment: I have understood what you are asking but i think you haven't understand what i suggested. Try 'Scene scene2 = new Scene(pane2);' instead of  'root.getChildren().setAll(pane2);' and add it in a new stage like 'stage2.setScene(scene2)' and show the stage 'stage2.show()' ,if you want a new scene. And if you want the Same scene then add
'root.setPrefHeight(90);
root.setPrefWidth(384);'  lines in the try portion of signin method

Comment: You can also call `Stage.sizeToScene()` after setting the new root of a scene, instead of replacing the scene entirely.